# LAN to LAN over internet

Tags: internet, local-area-network

Hy everybody,

I have one crazy question :) Is it possible to connect two computers over Internet in such a way so that you can see them both in a My Network Places as two PCs on the same LAN?

For example: At home I have 3 PCs and I can access them all and all the resources/services on them over my home LAN, thats super. But right now I am at dormitory and i have just my laptop with me, and I want to access all the files on my computers at home, i also want to use other resources and operate with services etc like on home LAN. Therefore the best thing it would be if i can see my home pc under My network places as another LAN pc. Is that possible?

I know i can have remote desktop or something, i even have webdav at home, but it's such a pain in the ass, and i can't watch movies that i have on my home pc :)
I was thinking if I can use putty to ssh home, and then use "net use" command to somehow tunnel to my home pc and map a drive on my laptop. yea i know i have crazy ideas :)

thanks and regards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I looked on that VPN and I figured out that you can create VPN directly from within windows "integrated" VPN throught Network Connections -> create a new connection. What i want to ask is there any reason not to use this already present VPN server?
Or is it better to use OpenVNP or Hamachi?

Answer (score 8):

This crazy solution to your crazy idea is called [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) :) You might try [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) for your needs though.

Answer (score 4):

Why not [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/) 
free and secure based on openssl to provide encryption, and it's under GPL.
It will help you creating point-to-point or server-to-multiclient encrypted tunnels between host computers.
And it is available on Solaris, Linux, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Mac OS X, and Windows 2000/XP/Vista.

Comment: I'd say because hamachi is simpler to use (eventhough OpenVPN is a great project), and works with NAT-to-NAT.

Comment: Again what blank3 said.  Why use a Claymore when all you need is a steak knife?  After he uses Hamachi and learns more about networking OpenVPN will be a great solution to look into.

Comment: +1 OpenVPN - GPL all the way.

Comment: Another +1 for free and open software.  Control your own destiny.